# Which data persistence options are available on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I know already:

Core Data, SQLite3, Property List Serialization, NSCoding with NSCoder (encode / decode)... what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another framework is [BNRPersistence](http://github.com/hillegass/BNRPersistence), which uses Tokyo Cabinet (I haven't tried it, so I don't know how good it is).  Other than that, you can do pretty much anything you want--[JSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON) or custom [XML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML) come to mind, but you can also use pretty much any C-based library.

Answer (score 0):

You listed the standard ones.  Of course you've got access to a file system, so you can pretty much do anything.  What are you looking for?